# Understanding How Many Times Nested Loops Will Run

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

I am trying to understand how many times the statement "x = x + 1" is executed in the code below, as a function of "n":

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
  for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
    for (k=1; k<=j; k++)
       x = x + 1 ;
```

If I am not wrong the first loop is executed *n* times, and the second one *n(n+1)/2* times, but on the third loop I get lost. That is, I can count to see how many times it will be executed, but I can't seem to find the formula or explain it in mathematical terms.

Can you?

By the way this is not homework or anything. I just found on a book and thought it was an interesting concept to explore.

Comment: Do you want to calculate exactly how many times it will execute, or are you just after the big-O estimate?

Comment: I want the exact formula. Big-O estimate is straight forward I believe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider the loop `for (i=1; i <= n; i++)`. It's trivial to see that this loops *n* times. We can draw this as:

```
* * * * *
```

Now, when you have two nested loops like that, your inner loop will loop *n(n+1)/2* times. Notice how this forms a triangle, and in fact, numbers of this form are known as [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

```
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

So if we extend this by another dimension, it would form a tetrahedron. Since I can't do 3D here, imagine each of these layered on top of each other.

```
* * * * *     * * * *     * * *     * *     *
* * * *       * * *       * *       *
* * *         * *         *
* *           *
*
```

These are known as the [tetrahedral numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number), which are produced by this formula:

```
n(n+1)(n+2)
-----------
     6
```

You should be able to confirm that this is indeed the case with a small test program.

If we notice that *6 = 3!*, it's not too hard to see [how this pattern generalizes to higher dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figurate_number#Triangular_numbers):

```
n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+r-1)
---------------------
         r!
```

Here, *r* is the number of nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd inner loop is the same as the 2nd inner loop, but your *n* is a formula instead.

So, if your outer loop is *n* times...

and your 2nd loop is `n(n+1)/2` times...

your 3rd loop is....

`(n(n+1)/2)((n(n+1)/2)+1)/2`

It's rather brute force and could definitely be simplified, but it's just algorithmic recursion.

Comment: +1, but it needs some additional explanation. Writing down the formula and doing the substitutions would be nice.

Comment: I noticed that, but how would you express that in a single formula?

Comment: I came up with that as well, but it doesn't seem to be right when you plug some sample numbers. For example, when n=3 that equation gives 21 right? But the answer should be 10.

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical formula is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%28k%2a%28k%2b1%29/2%29).

It is O(n^3) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

This number is equal to the number of triples {a,b,c} where a<=b<=c<=n.
Therefore it can be expressed as a [Combination with repetitions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition). In this case the total number of combinations with repetitions is: n(n+1)(n+2)/6

Answer (score 0):

> 1 + (1+2) + (1+ 2+ 3 ) +......+ (1+2+3+...n)

Answer (score 0):

You know how many times the second loop is executed so can replace the first two loops by a single one right? like

```
for(ij = 1; ij < (n*(n+1))/2; ij++)
   for (k = 1; k <= ij; k++)
      x = x + 1;
```

Applying the same formula you used for the first one where 'n' is this time n(n+1)/2 you'll have ((n(n+1)/2)*(n(n+1)/2+1))/2 - times the x = x+1 is executed.

Comment: T(T(n))? Do you think it's O(n^4) ?

Comment: I came up with that as well, but it doesn't seem to be right when you plug some sample numbers. For example, when n=3 that equation gives 21 right? But the answer should be 10. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Obviously three nested loops give an asimptotical complexity of O(n^3).

Comment: yeah, I didn't think it well, you must build from bottom up and not top down. hammar explained it very well